# how to sql server backup on tsclient

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name

SET @path = '\\tsclient\d:\'

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM CC.master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'
BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

then show error

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   Cannot open backup device '\tsclient\d:\Deecoup_20131022.BAK'. Operating system error 67(The network name cannot be found.).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to back up to such a path. Use a **local** drive on the server, or a **network path (UNC)** that the server can write to

Comment: Yes I use Network Path UNC how solve this problem

Comment: `\\tsclient\d:` is **not** a regular UNC path ..... `\\datastore\DataShare` would be. As I said: I don't think you can back up to such a path

Comment: My Database on Remote but I want backup on my local computer how define path in sql server 2008

Comment: In that case, you have to create a **share** on your local computer, and allow the remote SQL Server machine to write into that share

Comment: Normally copy all files and folder remote to local but through sql server it can't

Answer (score 0):

For those who still want an answer to this: use the drive letter without the colon in the path.  `\\tsclient\d` is a drive, `\\tsclient\d:` isn't.